# If the second derivative not exist, does the first derivative not exist also?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Since the second derivative is defined in terms of the first derivative, if f'' does not exist, does it imply that f' does not exist also? Similarly, if f' does not exist, does it imply that f'' not exist?

Comment: You may start with an analogous question: if $g'$ does not exist, does $g$ not exist?

Comment: @MinWu Not necessarily. If we look at |x|, the function exists everywhere but it's not differentiable at x = 0.

Comment: Good. Now what if $f$ is such that $f'(x)=|x|$?

Comment: Thank you I get it. What if f' DNE? I think it would make sense to say then that f'' does not exist as well. If I consider f(x) = |x|, I guess I'm not sure what happens to the second derivative at x = 0. Is it zero, or is it undefined (a hole), for the second derivative at x=0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about
$$
f(x) = x|x| \ .
$$

Comment: What if f' DNE? I think it would make sense to say then that f'' does not exist as well. If I consider f(x) = |x|, I guess I'm not sure what happens to the second derivative at x = 0. Is it zero, or is it undefined (a hole), for the second derivative at x=0?

Comment: @Buddhapus Draw the graph. That function is differentiable. It's derivative is $|x|$, at every $x$. The derivative itself is differentiable everywhere except at $0$, where the limit defining the derivative does not exist.  The derivative of $|x|$ does indeed "have a hole" (speaking informally) so the second derivative of $x|x|$ does too. That's the best explanation I can give - hope it's enough to help you.

Answer (score 0):

That is not necessarily true. If you can find a function that is not differentiable everywhere, then just set that to the first derivative and you'll get that the second derivative is also not differentiable. For instance, the piecewise function $f(x)=\begin{cases} x^3,&\text{if x<0 }\\x^2&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$. It is obviously not differentiable at $x=0$ since the two-sided limit DNE, but its integral is obviously $g(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{x^4}{4}&\text{if x<0}\\ \dfrac{x^3}{3}&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$. Thus, $g(x)$ is an example of a function where the first derivative exists at a point but the second derivative does not.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler example, consider $f(x)=x^{3/2}$. Then:
$$f'(x)=\frac32x^{1/2}\\
f''(x)=\frac34x^{-1/2}$$
Do they exist at $x=0$?